# Checking my proof of finding a limit

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find all the $a\in \mathbb R$ values which we get the following limit:

$$L=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^2+ax-2a}{(x^2-1)(x+a)}$$

to be finite. I don't see any problem just inserting $a$ into the limit so we get $\frac{1}{a+1}$ so for $a\neq -1$ we get a finite limit. Is it that easy?

Comment: What do you get if $a=-1$?

Comment: @NickGuerrero oops, I meant $a\neq -1$. Will edit.

Comment: What is in the case $$a=1$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner we get $\frac{3}{4}$ no?

Answer (score 1):

Your result $$\frac{2a^2-2a}{(a^2-1)2a}$$ can be written as $$\frac{2a(a-1)}{(a-1)(a+1)2a}=\frac{1}{a+1}$$ if $$a\ne -1$$

Comment: My question is if its correct to just insert $a$ into the equation?

Comment: Yes this is correct if the denominator $$(a^2-1)2a$$ is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, as long as we don't have $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, yes it is that easy and inserting $a$ is enough. And the answer becomes $a \in \mathbb{R}-\{-1\}$.

**EDIT:** By the warning from fleablood, we should also consider the case where we can have $\frac{0}{0}$. Here, note that in order for nominator to be $0$, we must have $2a^2-2a = 0 \implies a = 0 \lor a = 1$.

**Case 1:** $a = 0$. In this case, we have 
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{(x^2-1)} = 0 \ne \frac{1}{a+1} = 1$$

**Case 2:** $a = 1$. In this case, we have
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^2+x-2}{(x^2-1)(x+1)} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{(x^2-1)(x+1)} =  \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x+2)}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{3}{4} \ne \frac{1}{a+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: But you *DO* get $\frac 00$ if $a = 1$ and $x=a$.

Comment: For $a = 1$, we have $\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{(x+1)^2(x-1)} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x+2}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{3}{4}$. I think you are right because it is not $\frac{1}{2}$, in which we insert $a$.